# How do I add Apache CouchDB service to Windows service on Windows 10 using CouchDB 1.6.1

Tags: windows, windows-10, couchdb, couchdb-1.6

I have been trying to install `CouchDB 1.6.1` on Windows 10 and for some reason `"Apache CouchDB"` is not added to my windows service. When I install `CouchDB 2.1.1` the service is successfully added.

I don't think that `CouchDB 1.6.1` is deprecated for Windows 10. If so please let me know.

If `CouchDB 1.6.1` Is not deprecated for Windows 10 please let me know what is going wrong during my installation.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know the answer to your question, but be aware that CouchDB 1.6.1 should no longer be used, as it has some incredibly serious security flaws. Please use 1.7.1 or 2.1.1 instead.

Comment: @Flimzy I have tried it with 1.7.1 But I face the same problem. It works with version 2.1.1 but I was wondering why it does not add the service on the earlier versions. No where does it state that couchDB 1.7.1 or 1.6.1 does not work on Windows 10.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that in Windows 10 both CouchDb 1.6.1 & 1.7.1 do not start automatically after reboot? If yes then look at [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/748736/apache-couchdb-service-terminates-on-windows-10-single-language) , which solved my problem.